# How to override the 2nd Object JSON with 1st JSON object

Tags: java, json

I have a situation where I need to override 2nd JSON object value to 1st.

JSON original  :-

```
{
    "products": {
        "productsApp15": {
            "status": "active",
            "attribute_set": "Apparel",
            "name": "productsApp16",
            "product_type": "product",
            "code": "productsApp16"
        }
    }
}
```

My 1st object :-

```
{
    "productsApp15": {
        "attribute_set": "Apparel",
        "status": "active",
        "name": "productsApp16",
        "product_type": "product",
        "code": "productsApp16"
    }
}
```

My 2nd object :-

```
{
    "attribute_set": "Apparel",
    "status": "active",
    "name": "productsApp16",
    "product_type": "product",
    "code": "try"
}
```

If you see the value of key -> `code` is updated here. I want this change in my real or 1st JSON object so I can pass it to my Payload

My Code:-

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

    JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
    String firstName = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();

    System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName);

    jsonObject2.remove("code");
    jsonObject2.put("code", "try");

    JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
    String firstName2 = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();
    System.out.println("The first name is: " + jsonObject3);

    JSONObject combined = new JSONObject();
    combined.put("Object1", jsonObject1);
    combined.put("Object2", jsonObject3);
    String firstName3 = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();
    System.out.println("The first name is: " + combined);
```

My Main objective :- I am reading a file which contain my JSON, As you can see my object is again inside an another object .

I want to update the value and then want to pass it to payload.

**But how to get the original JSON structure with updated value?**

Is it possible?

Comment: is it always 'code' which is different ?

Comment: no it's just an attempt to achieve functionality .. creating framework of API is not as an easy as I thought :(

Comment: pardon? I meant is it just the code attribute of your json object which is different? Or can other attributes be different as well? And doesn't your current code work?

Comment: The Key will always be same.. any value can be different ..

Answer (score 1):

By Constructing the Java classes against the structure that is required in JSON, this can be achieved.

Messing up with JSON with JSON readers and parser is risky.

```
public class Products{
    private List<Product> productsList;
}

public class Product{
    private Map<String, ProProps> map = new HashMap<>();
    class ProProps{
       private String code;
       private String name;
       ...
    }
}
```

This gives you to map the objects and values.

Get the value of product that you want by key and replace the required props that you want.

Though the conversion of Java - Json takes place, there can be many extensions that can happen when you develop.

You can use [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) example to convert and do the manipulations required.

Comment: my problem is the my JSON structure having object inside an object ... The simple JSON will work for me fine but my situation is lil complex

Comment: The above java classes in answer don't support the Json that you have posted in the question ? Yes, nested and hierarchy of objects are required for this and the structure says the same

Comment: do you mean JSONParser  and JSONObject?

Comment: To solve the problem with replacing the objects at runtime, prefer Java objects then Json manipulation. I didnt mention about JSONParser~JSONObject usage, though you can use them.

Comment: ok ... Thanks @VInayVeluri .. I will try your link  ...  hope that it can handle situation like JSON structure having object inside an object